# Calculate ssh public key fingerprint into base64, why do I have an extra '='?

Tags: python, hash, base64

`ssh-keygen -lf ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` gives:

`2048 SHA256:nVDFXqK06A4dwQYjBR3MHglFllTCjSHVNgYcCeRCNaQ root@tianhe-windy (RSA)`

Then I try to calculate the `sha256` fingerprint on my own.

`cat ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` gives:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC/Ukz/o8b2L4fYyACOJOnFh8KOE/DypW9Dt3s8gZqKTb3W2BPmghLZyFeMQAjpVLJ/z414ydvb67AE9nyOQq1oMRbAyjbu97ocJ4UHXM6UO0wSRUF/fwtxfPju2p2hbVN7PqCV5+3cDUEIR1mVM8j6sdT7YbMTsZJab9gDlLD76ZKLCYLR1GSHNbxDp4DpMAkJsoS8F6ee+OwV6SiDvI3N6XDwrAASLNy09s2eid3H1YUSq276J5TLsZiKMPDgs7O3Tw2uMPkdzTdWSYJ/w0hyVO5YZW44JzSxg3PubV08eHPQWi17RwT7fa+QPvRw87YnACzFusZHOxQDxzQfCohH root@tianhe-windy
```

I copy the base64 encoded public key, from `A` to `H`, no whitespaces.

Then I do:

```
import hashlib
import base64

b64pubkey = 'AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC/Ukz/o8b2L4fYyACOJOnFh8KOE/DypW9Dt3s8gZqKTb3W2BPmghLZyFeMQAjpVLJ/z414ydvb67AE9nyOQq1oMRbAyjbu97ocJ4UHXM6UO0wSRUF/fwtxfPju2p2hbVN7PqCV5+3cDUEIR1mVM8j6sdT7YbMTsZJab9gDlLD76ZKLCYLR1GSHNbxDp4DpMAkJsoS8F6ee+OwV6SiDvI3N6XDwrAASLNy09s2eid3H1YUSq276J5TLsZiKMPDgs7O3Tw2uMPkdzTdWSYJ/w0hyVO5YZW44JzSxg3PubV08eHPQWi17RwT7fa+QPvRw87YnACzFusZHOxQDxzQfCohH'
sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
sha256.update(base64.b64decode(b64pubkey))
b64fingerprint = base64.b64encode(sha256.digest())
print(b64fingerprint)
```

and get

`nVDFXqK06A4dwQYjBR3MHglFllTCjSHVNgYcCeRCNaQ=`

compare to the one caculated by `ssh-keygen`:

`nVDFXqK06A4dwQYjBR3MHglFllTCjSHVNgYcCeRCNaQ`

I get an extra `=` too when calculating `ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Btw, how do I use `ssh-keygen` to produce hex instead of base64 characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong, it's just that SSH by convention omits any trailing padding. You can remove any trailing `=` signs yourself as well; they do not encode any data.

The Python `base64` routines implement the standard base64 algorithm which is specified to return an even multiple of four characters of encoded data. The origins are from the MIME standard for email, I believe.

Comment: Do you know why public key fingerprint now is given in base64 format instead of hex ? I see old question that fingerprint is displayed in hex format like `08:EF...`

Comment: It's too long to be communicated by reading it out loud anyway, so a more compact format makes more sense for copy/paste. A binary format would be more compact still, of course, but not robust for copy/paste; base64 seems pretty ideal (though there are now alternatives like base85 which would be slightly more compact, but less ubiquitously supported by various tools and programming languages).

Comment: So base64 wins (only) because of shorter length, while both(hex) are good at copy/paste?

Comment: That's my conjecture, yes. Or in other words, hex has drawbacks and no benefits for this use case.